# How did Fred and George fly out of Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter

When Fred and George leave in *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*, they summon their brooms and fly away out of Hogwarts.

How was this possible with all the protective enchantments protecting the castle, preventing flying and apparition? Do the enchantments only keep people from flying *in*?

Comment: I can't remember a protection against flying things in Hogwarts. I mean, owls get in and out all the time too.

Comment: Why should you make a protection to get out ? I think I remember it as just protecting Hogwarts against enemies getting in. Or would you like to keep your enemies on your ground if they want to get out ?

Comment: The protection against flying over Hogwarts boarders were, I think, only mentioned during the 6th book (while Dumbledore and Harry were returning from the cave) but this was after Voldemort's return had been publicized. Maybe the protection hadn't been made so strong during the fifth book? We should remember that before this incident, Ron and Harry flew into Hogwarts in the car in the second book.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In *Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone* it appears that there is no current restriction against flying in or out of Hogwarts. As in the same book Charlie Weasly flies in with friends to pick up Norbert the dragon.
Again we see that extra restrictions are put into place after Voldemort's return, open return.

Answer (score -1):

In Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince, Harry and Dumbledore fly in and out of Hogwarts on broomsticks to Hogsmeade in order to apparate to the cave. I'm pretty sure this indicates that there were no barriers against flying in or out of Hogwarts, since if they just got that restriction removed temporarily it should have been just as easy to remove the apparition barrier temporarily

Comment: -1 dumbledore specifically removes protection to allow them to fly in. They also don't fly out